# Select on .csv file stops working after columns 1 and 2

Tags: sql, excel, vba, csv

I have the following line in a `.csv` file:
`1234;Einkauf;26.08.2015;137873;616005;50308;Hiag;4100000;Place Rd. 8, 9999 Ort, HST;;;Test Place Rd. Ort;2000;VSM80;185.05;12;155.55;0.02`

I run the following code:

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strPath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"

sQuery = vbNullString
sQuery = sQuery & "SELECT * FROM " & strFileName
sQuery = sQuery & ";"

rs.Open sQuery, cn

If Not (rs.EOF Or rs.BOF) Then
    If InclHeaders = False Then rs.Move 1

    ReDim rsArr(1 To 1)
    i = 1
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        ReDim Preserve rsArr(1 To i)
        For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            rsArr(i) = Trim(rsArr(i)) & " " & rs.Fields(j)
        Next j
        i = i + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

Once it gets here, the first two times are fine:
`rsArr(i) = Trim(rsArr(i)) & " " & rs.Fields(j)`

The third field returns 0 although it shouldn't, so the value for `rsArr(i)` is `1234;Einkauf;26.08.2015;137873;616005;50308;Hiag;4100000;Place Rd. 8, 9999 Ort`

I am at a loss why this is the case. It loops through the fields, so it isn't stopping after the second one.

[The file has two header rows that's why I am moving the `rs`. It doesn't matter though since the error keeps occuring no matter how many header rows.

Edit: First five lines (I get the same problem if I remove the first two header rows though, so treat with caution).

```
; Auftrag: 9161779,9162090,9162298,61601060,61601061,61601062,61601069,61601064,61601065,61601066,61601067
Konto;KontoBez;Datum;Blg Nr;OpNr;PkNr;PkName;Auftrag;AuftragText;Code;Vor;Buchungstext;G-Konto;MWST;BVS;BNS;NNS;Skonto
1234;Einkauf;10.10.2014;135729;14-02504;50309;Hofstetter;41401060;Place Rd. 8, 9999 Ort;;;Hofstetter Place Rd. 8, 9999 Ort;2000;VSM80;100.75;100.58;100.05;0.02
1234;Einkauf;10.10.2014;138182;1070011530;50326;Roto;41401060;Place Rd. 8, 9999 Ort;;;Roto Place Rd. 8, 9999 Ort;2000;VSM80;12.80;10.62;15.39;0.03
1234;Kunden 13;10.10.2014;5795;92140457;81853;;41401060;Place Rd. 8, 9999 Ort;;;AK:Place Rd. 8, 9999 Ort;1100;USt80;-12500.00;-12550.00;-12555.67;0
```

Comment: You only have a one dimension array. Don't you need 2? On the very first iteration of the loop, your array is defined as rsArr(1). That means when you are looping through the columns, you only get to populate rsArr(0) and rsArr(1) before you're out of space. That's because you've dimmed the array dynamically for the number of rows you're going to have, but you haven't dimmed any space for the columns.

Comment: I am concateing the lines first and then in a second iteration split them by ";". The problem is the data source (i.e. csv file) is a clusterfuck and I need to manipulate it in order to use it. So for the time being I only need a one dimensional Array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but with the multiple headers is it possible that there is some datatype confusion?  If so, I think the `IMEX=1;` at the end of your extended properties helps manage the situations with varying datatypes:

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
    strPath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=1"";"
```

If this doesn't work, maybe show the actual first 5 or so lines of your CSV file, with headers and all?  It's possible something will jump out.

As an alternative, I couldn't help but notice your data file doesn't appear to have quoted values.  If this is consistent across the entire file, you could take the lazy approach and read the file as a normal delimited file:

```
Dim fields() As String

Open strPath & "\" & strFileName for Input as #1

Do Until EOF(1)
  Line Input #1, line
  fields = Split(line, ",")
  ' your other stuff here
Loop

Close #1
```

With the normal caveat that this is a far cry from a robust CSV parser...

Comment: I added the first five lines of the `.csv` file.

Comment: I now used your solution to combat my problem. I still find it extremely weird that it didn't work properly.